# What is the senior parent chain in the following compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

Will the IUPAC name be (2-hydroxymethyl) but-3-ynoic acid (or) 2-ethynyl-3-hydroxy propanoic acid?

Comment: Please note that the triple bond shall be depicted in a linear fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important simplified criteria for the choice of a principal chain are:

1. greater number of suffixes
2. longest chain
3. greater number of multiple bonds
4. lower locants for suffixes
5. lower locants for multiple bonds
6. greater number of prefixes
7. lower locants for prefixes
8. lower locants for substituents cited first as a prefix in the name

The corresponding wording of the rules taken from *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* is as follows.

> **P-44.1** SENIORITY ORDER FOR PARENT STRUCTURES
>
> When there is a choice, the senior parent structure is chosen by applying the following criteria, in order, until a decision is reached. These criteria must always be applied before those applicable to rings and ring systems (see P-44.2) and to chains (see P-44.3). Then criteria applicable to both chains and rings or ring systems given in P-44.4 are considered.
>
> **P-44.1.1** The senior parent structure has the maximum number of substituents corresponding to the principal characteristic group (suffix) or senior parent hydride in accord with the seniority of classes (P-41) and the seniority of suffixes (P-43).
>
> (…)
>
> **P-44.3.2** The principal chain has the greater number of skeletal atoms [criterion (b) in P-44.3].
>
> (…)
>
> **P-44.4.1** If the criteria of P-44.1 through P-44.3, where applicable, do not effect a choice of a senior parent structure, the following criteria are applied successively until there are no alternatives remaining. These criteria are illustrated in P-44.4.1.1 through P-44.4.1.12.
>
> The senior ring, ring system, or principal chain:
>
> (a) has the greater number of multiple bonds (P-44.4.1.1);
>
> (b) has the greater number of double bonds (P-44.4.1.2);
>
> (…)
>
> (h) has the lower locant for an attached group expressed as a suffix (P-44.4.1.8);
>
> (…)
>
> (j) has the lower locant(s) for endings or prefixes that express changes in the level of hydrogenation, i.e., for ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings and ‘hydro/dehydro’ prefixes (P-44.4.1.10);
>
> (…)
>
> **P-45.2.1** The preferred IUPAC name is based on the senior parent structure that has the maximum number of substituents cited as prefixes (other than ‘hydro/dehydro’) to the parent structure.
>
> **P-45.2.2** The preferred IUPAC name is based on the senior parent structure that has the lower locant or set of locants for substituents cited as prefixes (other than ‘hydro/dehydro’) to the parent structure.
>
> **P-45.2.3** The preferred IUPAC name is based on the senior parent structure that has the lower locant or set of locants for substituents cited as prefixes to the parent structure (other than ‘hydro/dehydro’ prefixes) in their order of citation in the name.
>
> (…)

You have correctly identified the suffix (“oic acid”) for the principal characteristic group. The next criterion for the principal chain is the greater number of skeletal atoms (i.e. the longest chain). Thus, the principal chain corresponds to the but-3-ynoic acid part and not to the 3-hydroxypropanoic acid part since but-3-ynoic acid has a longer chain than propanoic acid. Therefore, the correct name is **2-(hydroxymethyl)but-3-ynoic acid.**

[image: 2-(hydroxymethyl)but-3-ynoic acid]

Comment: "greater number of suffixes" I don't understand this. How can there ever be more than one suffixes? Do you have an example?

Comment: @GaurangTandon As you can see from the quoted rules, ‘greater number of suffixes’ is my simplified short version of ‘The senior parent structure has the maximum number of substituents corresponding to the principal characteristic group (suffix)’. For example the principical chain in 1-[3-(3-hydroxypropyl)phenyl]ethane-1,2-diol is ‘ethane-1,2-diol’ (two substitutents corresponding to the principal characteristic group, i.e. suffix ‘ol’) and not the longer ‘propan-1-ol’ (only one substituent corresponding to the principal characteristic group).

Comment: Oh, thanks! :) That helped. Though you might want to lengthen that "simplified short version" to something like "greater count of the principal functional group" to make it more unambiguous. I am not sure if I am the first person to be confused by that...

Comment: Honestly though, this simplified criteria is **so immensely useful.** Throughout the past year ever since I've been searching for decent IUPAC nomenclature I've never seen it before. You should really make a nice introductory page sort of thing for it. Now that I have fully understood it I really repent not knowing it earlier.